# How to add a bearer token to a post request using Moshi and Retrofit 2 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to submit a post request using Retrofit 2 and moshi but I have the following errors in the headers

here is my code

```
fun createVideoUrlService(): CreateVideoUrl{
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("*******")
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
return retrofit.create(CreateVideoUrl::class.java)

}


interface CreateVideoUrl {
  @Headers({
    "Content-Type:application/json",
    "Authorization:Bearer 
   *******"
  })
  @POST("*******")
  fun createUser(@Body constructUrl: ConstructUrl)
  :Call<Resp>
 }
```

However the headers section is red. How can I add Bearer token to my post request

Comment: Do you use a static const in @Headers arguments  instead of  `*******` ? Which error do you get when try to build the app ?

Comment: I get 400 error code

Comment: Do you get a 400 response code 400 From server  when call to createUser() ? Code 400 means `Bad Request`. Please try to log you request body by adding interceptor  to okhttp client, like: HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }